# Looking for a non-usual symbol for semidirect product

Tags: symbols

What I want are the symbols used in the textbook *Theory of group representations and applications* of Asom O. Barut and Ryszard Raczka (2n ed.) for semidirect sum and semidirect product. I upload a photo.

[image]

I have been looking for in Unicode symbols and i don't find anything, so probably it is going to be diffcult.

Thanks.

**Remark.** This question have been marked as *possible duplicate question*. I don't agree with that. I've tried to use Detexify to find my symbol, but it didn't recognize it. Probably I should study The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List better, but that is another question. Any of the answers provided in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character) solves my problem.

Comment: I've tried to use Detexify but it didn't recognize them. So I don't think it is duplicated.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build the symbols yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\loplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\dog@lsemi{+}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lotimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\dog@lsemi{\times}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\roplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\dog@rsemi{+}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rotimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\dog@rsemi{\times}}}

\newcommand{\dog@rsemi}[2]{\dog@semi{#1}{#2}{-90,90}}
\newcommand{\dog@lsemi}[2]{\dog@semi{#1}{#2}{270,90}}
\newcommand{\dog@semi}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{\raisebox{-\dp\z@}{%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{\variable@rule{#1}}
    \roundcap
    \put(0.5,0.5){\makebox(0,0){\raisebox{\dp\z@}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}
    \put(0.5,0.5){\arc[#3]{0.5}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\variable@rule}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8  
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont3\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont3\else
        \scriptscriptfont3\relax
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\roplus B\rotimes C\loplus D \lotimes E$

$\scriptstyle \roplus\rotimes\loplus\lotimes$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, note that the standard `\oplus` and `\otimes` are lighter than `+` and `\times`, so you may want to redefine also them in a similar way, using the full circle.

Answer (score 15):

I have just found it. It is defined in `stix` package, as: `\oplusrhrim` and `\otimesrhrim`.

[image]

Comment: Notice that many authors (ab)use the $\ltimes$ and $\rtimes$ symbols for that (mainly because issues with the interplay between stix and amsmath, see section 2.2 of the stix manual).

Comment: I thought `\rtimes` and `\ltimes` were the snatdard symbols. They aren't the usual?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard"? They come with a vertical bar on the either left- or right-hand side, and thus resemble your symbols, and they are widely used in the literature (even though the one you found look more like the original ones).

Comment: What I wanted to say is that I thought the ''canonical'' to denote the semidirect product was the `\rtimes`, for example in Wikipedia's article. And that until Barut and Raczka's book, I'd not seen these symbols. But I agree with you. From my point of view, stix's symbols seems more natural or ''correct''.